# Run "./" bash/batch file with cygwin

Tags: linux, bash, batch-file, cmd, cygwin

Well the idea goes as followed,

I have a bash file for linux, there I obviously run it by making `./my_run`.
The problem is I'm in windows so I downloaded and installed cygwin.
I added cygwin bin to the Enviromental Variables and check that at least "ls" works so I guessed I did it well.
When I try to run it with the cmd it displays:

```
'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

As if the cygwin variables were not correctly installed (as I said I tried ls and works).
Then I tried it directly with cygwin and when doing the `./my_run` I got it to work right.

So how is that I can use some commands like ls but when doing ./ it doesn't work on the cmd? How can I fix this?

Comment: Could you post the content of the script?

Comment: Sorry, the script now works, the thing is when I changed to my_run.bat and then I got back to my_run the file was "corrupt" so I had problems. When downloading the original file again from git it started working but ONLY on cygwin. Now I just wanna now why it doesn't work on cmd. 
PS: thank you! that was a quick response

Comment: Wow, a question that _actually_ needs both the bash and batch-file tags. That said, the two languages are completely different and you either need to convert your Windows newlines to Unix newlines (any decent text editor has this option) or completely rewrite the script in batch.

Comment: Then please answer the question and mark it as answered. So people don't think they need to answer

Comment: Voting to close as the problem was based on non recreatable errors.

Comment: Well is not yet solved... I just change the question so that I deleted the first part... Maybe I can just leave the original and answer my fix so that people see the partial answer to the question (it was question 2 in the original one but no 1)

Comment: Also, I'm surprised things like `ls` are working at all. Cygwin is a *NIX terminal emulator and *NIX environment stuff only works inside of it. Windows is still Windows.

Comment: Use `"./my_run"` (put the command in double quotes)

Comment: Unix uses `/` as path separator while Windows uses `\ `...

Comment: Are you sure you are executing those commands in a cygwin environment?  When you say _I added cygwin bin to the Enviromental Variables_ what do you exactly mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, cygwin is only a shared library and a lot of stuff (the programs) using it (read [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) doc).  `cygwin.dll` changes internally path resolution `/` chars to allow you to say `./my_script` and converts it to `.\my_script` before doing the actual windows call, it also adds the proper extension to executables to allow it to execute windows binaries.  This magic persists as long as you use it.  `cmd.exe` is a Microsoft Windows command shell that is completely unaware of Cygwin's shared library and by that reason it doesn't use it, so it will not call it for path translation, even if you populate the environment of zetabytes of stuff.  When you run in Cygwin terminal, you are running `bash` shell, which is a Cygwin executable, linked to `cygwin.dll`.  It manages to use Cygwin library for all the unix system call emulations, so when you pass it e.g. to `exec("./my_script", ...);`, it internally converts that to try for `./my_script`, then `.\my_script`, `./my_script.exe`, ... and the same for `.com` and `.bat` extensions.

This fact often makes some people to say that Cygwin is not a good, efficient, environment.  But the purpose was not to be efficient (and it is, as it caches entries and makes things best to be efficient) but to be compatible.

In your example `ls` is a Cygwin executable that mimics the `/bin/ls` executable from unix systems.  It uses the Cygwin library, so all path resolution will be properly made (well, under some constraints, as you'll see after some testing) and everything will work fine.  But you cannot pretend all your Windows applications to suddenly transform themselves and begin working as if they where in a different environment.  This requires some try and error approach that you have to try yourself.  And read [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) documentation, it is very good and covers everything I've said here.

Answer (score 0):

If you open up Cygwin and run the command there you should be fine.

Comment: but why does cmd doesn't work? I mean... If there is a weird reason why adding env variables shouldn't work?... if so... how can it be that I'm using ls?

Comment: `./` is not an environment variable. It refers to your current directory. Does it work when you type `bash my_file` in cmd?